# HTML code for opening a video link in a new frame/window that will remain on top of main window, and move with it as it scrolls

Tags: html, iframe, scroll, popup, frames

I am a beginner and apologize if I do not use the correct terms. (I think that may be why I can't find an answer despite hours of searching and trying things out.)

I have finally figured out how to create a video link that has the video pop-up in a new, smaller window. But I would like this new window to stay on top of the main window, so that I can watch the video while I'm scrolling through and reading the contents of the main window.

I have seen it done in very simple HTML code with a moving box of text, but I can't for the life of me figure out how to make the new pop-up video link work.

Here is the code I'm using for the new smaller window, just with a different video source:

```
<a href="#" onClick="MyWindow=window.open('http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6zwbSDpROm8','MyWindow','toolbar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=no, menubar=no,scrollbars=no,resizable=no,width=600,height=300'); return false;">Click Here to open video in a new window</a>
```

I read in forum entries that it is not possible to make a pop-up window stay on top, so I'm open to other options, such as creating an iframe that will then move as I scroll down in the main window. Not sure if this is possible, though.

Comment: I think you need to look at Fancybox or something like that.

Comment: It looks like FancyBox elements are not meant to be interacted with at the same time as the main page, since there is an opacity around the new window. Maybe that's something that can be shut off? I'll look into it more.

Comment: Do you want the screen to be split in 2, or in another window?